# Do ConnectionPools have one connection, or many?

Tags: c#, sql-server

We have a web server which connects to a database using a single connection string, which makes it a strong candidate for being able to use a Connection Pool.

Do we need one SqlConnection object, or many?

*i.e.* Should we set up one connection in shared memory, and use that each time, or should we create a new one each time we want to use any connection object?

Is it the call to .Open() which assigns it from a pool, or the creating of a new object with the same connection string?

Also, do we need to call .Close() on the connection before it's released back into the pool, or is the variable going out of scope enough?

I read somewhere (I forget where exactly - sorry) that you shouldn't call close on connections in a pool, because it removes them from the pool somehow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should open a separate connection every time you need to access a database and close it once you're done with all the access. Do not keep your connections open for too long. It is not necessary and modern databases are definitely very good at handling multiple connections.

You can leave the management of the connection pool to SQL Server - it will do a good job as long as you'll not try to prevent it.

It's best to use local connection object and not share it across multiple parts of the code. You can use `using` pattern to make sure your connection will be closed:

```
using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("connectionstring"))
{
    conn.Open();
    // use your connection here
}
```

Comment: I appreciate that it's best to use "using", but if I have lots of legacy code which doesn't, do I need to worry, or will the dropping out of scope (and no variables pointing to it) close the connection and return it to the pool.

Comment: You can also use `Close()`, you don't have to use `using`.

Comment: No, connections are not closed when the variable holding them goes out of scope. I'm not 100% sure now, but if the thread holding the connection gets killed or finished, the connection will get closed. Certainly stopping the process which opened the connection closes the connection as well.

Answer (score 4):

It’s worth bearing in mind that an identical connection string will re-use a connection which has been returned the the pool, but changing it in any way will cause a new connection to be made to the server.

i.e. 
Assuming that SQLBox has IP 10.0.0.1

```
using (var conn = new SqlConnection(@"Server=10.0.0.1;...") {
                conn.Open();
                .. Do work ..
                conn.Close();
}
using (var conn = new SqlConnection(@"Server=SQLBox;…") {
                conn.Open(); // This will *NOT* reuse the connection from the pool.
                .. Do work ..
                conn.Close();
}
using (var conn = new SqlConnection(@"Server=10.0.0.1;...") {
                conn.Open(); // This *WILL* reuse the connection from the pool.
                .. Do work ..
                conn.Close();
}
```